# $A=\{(x,\sin(1/x):x>0\}$ and $B=\{(0,0),(-1,0)\}$ then $A\cup B$ is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

> $A=\{(x,\sin(1/x)):x>0\}$ and $B=\{(0,0),(-1,0)\}$ then $A\cup B$ is connected?

My Attempt:
$X=A\cup B$ is disconnected iff $cl(A)\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A \cap cl(B)=\emptyset$

Here $A\cap cl(B)=\emptyset$ but $cl(A)\cap B=\{(0,0)\}\neq \emptyset \implies A\cup B$ is **not disconnected.**
So $A\cup B$ is **connected.**

am I right **?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You probably mean $B=\{(0,0),(0,-1)\}$ instead?

Comment: No sir.... Its (-1,0)

Comment: But according to above thm X is connected

Comment: And is $B$ supposed to be a couple of points or an horizontal closed line segment? Last case will be more fun!

Comment: In my book ans is AUB is disconnected. so I got confused.....

Answer (score 2):

If $C=\{(x,y): X <-\frac  12 \}$ and $D=\{(x,y): x >-\frac  12 \}$ then $X=(X\cap C) \cup (X \cap D)$. This shows that $X$ is not connected.